# UITableView / Sections : different cells / Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, sections

I already have the cells in my first section but I don't know how to bring my cell2 specifically just in my second section:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
        return 4
        }
        if section == 1 {
            return pushUpArray.count
        }
        return section
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "section1")
        var cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "section2")
        
        
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "section1")
        
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        cell.textLabel?.text = TableViewValues[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = TableViewDetailValues[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "section2")
        }
        cell2.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        cell2.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row). Count: \(count) Time: \(Time)"
        
        
        
        return cell
        return cell2
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can check like "indexPath.section == 0" instead of  "cell2 == nil" just update you condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return cells depends on section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 4
    } else {
        return pushUpArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "section1")
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        cell.textLabel?.text = TableViewValues[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = TableViewDetailValues[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "section2")
        cell2.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        cell2.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row). Count: \(count) Time: \(Time)"
        return cell2
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```